# How can I get this script to loop X amount of times?

Tags: loops, scripting

I am trying to loop everything under groupadd coffee for 5 times for creating 5 new users at a time. Taking those variables and filling in the other commands. After all that is finished start again for a new user. I've searched up and down and can't seem to figure it out. Here is the script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #Script for adding users and groups

    if [ $(getent group Coffee) ]; then
        echo
    else
        sudo groupadd Coffee
    fi
        read -p "What is the new user's login ID? " username
        read -s -p "What is the user's password? " password 
    echo
        read -p "What is the new user's full name? " fullname
        read -p "What is the new user's initial group? " intgroup
        read -p "What is the new user's additional group? " addgroup

    if [ $(getent group $intgroup) ]; then
        echo
    else
        sudo groupadd $intgroup
    fi

    if [ $(getent group $addgroup) ]; then
        echo
    else
        sudo groupadd $addgroup
    fi
        sudo useradd -m -G Coffee,$intgroup,$addgroup $username

    if [ -z $password ] 
    then
        echo -e "newpass\nnewpass" | sudo passwd $username
    else 
        echo -e "$password\n$password" | sudo passwd $username
    fi
```

I know I may have to restructure this but I am hoping it is something simple I can add to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I got helped with.

```
<pre>
#!/bin/bash

sudo groupadd Coffee
# adds group Coffee to system

COUNTER=0
         while [  $COUNTER -lt 5 ]; do
             echo The counter is $COUNTER
echo
    read -p "What is the new user's login ID? " username
    read -s -p "What is the user's password? " password 
echo
    read -p "What is the new user's full name? " fullname
    read -p "What is the new user's initial group? " intgroup
    read -p "What is the new user's additional group? " addgroup
#prompts for variables

if [ $(getent group $intgroup) ]; then
    echo
else
    sudo groupadd $intgroup
fi
#checks to see if specified group is on the system


if [ $(getent group $addgroup) ]; then
    echo
else
    sudo groupadd $addgroup
fi
#checks to see if specified group is on the system

    sudo useradd -m -G Coffee,$intgroup,$addgroup $username
#creates home directory and adds user into groups


if [ -z $password ] 
then
    echo -e "newpass\nnewpass" | sudo passwd $username
else 
    echo -e "$password\n$password" | sudo passwd $username
fi
#changes password or gives default one
 let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
         done
echo
<code>
```